PostgreSQL, Query is very slow , supports Index Scan DESC and index skip scan operations?
I need to extract a small amount of data,
but the table is very large and has many indexed columns,
which makes the response time too slow
but, i do'nt want create new index.
because, table is not mine
Env
PostgreSQL 13 AWS RDS
Question
if PostgreSQL supports Index Scan DESC operations.
can i use it?
My expectation is that this query could be faster if it used an Index Scan Desc and Index Skip Scan
Query
SELECT
billingYearMonth AS billingYearMonth
, customerId       AS customerId
, childCustomerId  AS childCustomerId
, deptCustomerId   AS deptCustomerId
, cloudSupplyCode  AS cloudSupplyCode
, sum(usage) AS USAGE
FROM
bill_big_table A
WHERE
billingYearMonth     = '202407'
AND cloudSupplyCode  = '05'
AND KEYSORTORDER     = 3
GROUP BY
billingYearMonth
, customerId
, childCustomerId
, deptCustomerId
, cloudSupplyCode
ORDER BY
  billingYearMonth
, customerId
, childCustomerId
, deptCustomerId
, cloudSupplyCode 
OFFSET   0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY

Index columns (Normal)



Order
Column Name
Condition




1
billingyearmonth
=


2
customerid



3
childcustomerid



4
deptcustomerid



5
cloudsupplyinvoiceid



6
cloudsupplyinvoiceitemid



7
keybillingitemid



8
keysortorder
=


9
categorycode



10
cloudsupplycode
=



raw DATA
INVOICEYM = '202407'



keysortorder
cloudsupplycode
Rows





1
1
114



2
1
177



3
1
579



1
2
1,021



2
2
3,908



3
2
4,179



1
3
13



2
3
13



3
3
13



1
4
12,000



2
4
3,113,648



3
4
18,151,142



1
5
150



2
5
534



3
5
828
wanna this


1
6
3



2
6
3



3
6
3



1
7
3,601



2
7
49,871



3
7
74,491



1
9
381



2
9
2,394



3
9
2,394



1
10
29



2
10
56



3
10
56



1
12
102



2
12
2,505



3
12
3,556




Table rows 339,172,200
Disk Space 412G
Rel Size   189G
EXPLAIN PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.95..106420.59 rows=1000 width=42) (actual time=11842.405..1695652.907 rows=16 loops=1)
  Output: billingyearmonth, customerid, childcustomerid, deptcustomerid, cloudsupplycode, (sum(usage))
  Buffers: shared hit=78 read=1637059
  I/O Timings: read=3288604.358
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.95..7681370.57 rows=72180 width=42) (actual time=11842.403..1695652.889 rows=16 loops=1)
        Output: billingyearmonth, customerid, childcustomerid, deptcustomerid, cloudsupplycode, sum(usage)
        Group Key: a.billingyearmonth, a.customerid, a.childcustomerid, a.deptcustomerid, a.cloudsupplycode
        Buffers: shared hit=78 read=1637059
        I/O Timings: read=3288604.358
        ->  Index Scan using bill_big_table_pkey on public.bill_big_table a  (cost=0.95..7679565.03 rows=72249 width=42) (actual time=6203.945..1695652.135 rows=828 loops=1)
              Output: billingyearmonth, customerid, childcustomerid, deptcustomerid, cloudsupplyinvoiceid, cloudsupplyinvoiceitemid, cloudsupplyinvoicetype, keybillingitemid, keysortorder, categorycode, cloudsupplycode, categoryname, itemname, pricecurrency, originamount, exchangerate, exchangeratedate, totalkrwamount, billingtype, startdate, enddate, orderuserid, productcode, usage, usageunit, startdate_l, enddate_l, billingentity, tagresourceid, meteringtype
              Index Cond: (((a.billingyearmonth)::text = '202407'::text) AND (a.keysortorder = 3) AND (a.cloudsupplycode = '05'::bpchar))
              Buffers: shared hit=78 read=1637059
              I/O Timings: read=3288604.358
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=122 read=12
  I/O Timings: read=11.781
Planning Time: 13.274 ms
Execution Time: 1695653.003 ms


Adding a multi-column BTREE index to this table is the way to make your query faster. You’ve ruled that out, so there is nothing much we can do to help you, sorry to say.

There is no reason to think that either of those techniques would be useful for this query on the existing index.

You're not even ordering DESC, so why would an index that is ordered DESC be faster? The only thing you could do, but don't want to do, is a new index that covers all columns and results in an index-only-scan. That would reduce the IO load.

thank you for comment ,
I removed the condition. I can't create the index because it's not my table.
Also, they do not want to spend time creating an index (it's not  me).
I mentioned index scan DESC,    but what I actually wanted was index skip scan.
The index scan DESC was suggested
because the data distribution is suited for DESC.
